# Como atualizar o campo de resultado com base em critérios?

Tags: oracle

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE ALUNO (
  RA NUMBER(9),
  DISCIPLINA VARCHAR2(30),
  MEDIA NUMBER(3,1),
  CARGA_HORA NUMBER(2),
  FALTAS NUMBER(2),
  RESULTADO VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

E os seguintes dados:

```
INSERT INTO ALUNO VALUES (1,'SQL',7.5,80,20,'');
INSERT INTO ALUNO VALUES (2,'PLSQL',5.5,80,20,'');
INSERT INTO ALUNO VALUES (3,'MBD',7.5,80,40,'');
```

Tenho o seguinte sql:

```
select ra,
   Disciplina,
   Media,
   Carga_Hora,
   Faltas,
   case when (Media >= 7) and (trunc((Faltas / Carga_Hora * 100)) <= 25) then 'APROVADO'
        when (Media between 5 and 6.9) and (trunc((Faltas / Carga_Hora * 100)) <= 25) then 'EXAME'
   else 'REPROVADO'  end Resultado
```

from aluno
 order by ra

Preciso criar um bloco para preencher o campo resultado:

1. Se o aluno obteve média igual ou maior ou igual a 7.0 e suas faltas não ultrapassarem 25% da carga horária da disciplina o resultado será: `APROVADO`.
2. Se o aluno obteve média inferior a 7.0 e suas faltas não ultrapassarem 25% da carga horária da disciplina o resultado será: `EXAME`.
3. Para demais casos o resultado será: `REPROVADO`.

Comment: Tentei ajustar sua questão para ficar mais legível. Se tiver algo errado, não hesite em editá-la.

Answer (score 1):

Se a ideia é atualizar a tabela com os resultados, basta fazer um `UPDATE` com um `CASE`:

```
UPDATE ALUNO SET RESULTADO = (
    CASE
      WHEN MEDIA >= 7.0 AND FALTAS / CARGA_HORA <= 0.25 THEN 'APROVADO'
      WHEN FALTAS / CARGA_HORA <= 0.25 THEN 'EXAME'
      ELSE 'REPROVADO'
    END
  );
```

### [Demo no SqlFiffle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/381aa/1)

Comment: O segundo `WHEN` parece incompleto de acordo com a regra na pergunta: _"média inferior a 7.0 e suas faltas não ultrapassarem 25%"_, certo?

Comment: Fiz um ajuste na pergunta, adicionei a consulta sql pronta, agora como ter um bloco para fazer a inserção dos dados na coluna?

Comment: @Zuul Não estava incompleta, só errado! :\

Comment: @itasouza Basta adicionar sua condição `CASE` num comando `UPDATE`, conforme minha resposta.